# Which ciphers satisfies the "Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites" SSL Labs test requirement?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I've run [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com) test and it reports a warning that `This server does not support Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites. Grade will be capped to B from March 2018.`

Unfortunately, I have found nowhere nor in the [linked documentation](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices#23-use-secure-cipher-suites) which ciphers are the ones which are missing.

What are meant under the "Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites"?

The server runs Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Check this out. You can use a DHE cipher using a 2048 key. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51658.ssllabs-this-server-does-not-support-authenticated-encryption-aead-cipher-suites-grade-capped-to-b.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently working on the same problem myself and I'll link the answer here: [Security Exchange AEAD suites](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136180/tls-1-2-and-enable-only-aead-ciphers-suite-list)

The gist of it is as follows: All the suites for **Windows Server 2012 R2** are the AES GCM suites, like these:

- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P384
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384

If you didn't find it already, [Microsoft has a SSL/TLS suite overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt767781(v=vs.85).aspx) for all suites, default and non-default.

Comment: Strange. It seems I have them enabled but they are not reported by SSL Labs. As it is another question, I have created a new one https://serverfault.com/questions/895161/gcm-cipher-suites-are-enabled-but-not-discovered-by-ssl-labs-test

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, but as the current answer shows:"But these are all cipher suites which require an ECDSA certificate, i.e. with an ECC public key." I've made a CSR with the ECDSA enabled and the right priority selected in the GPO. My guess is that the certificate was not correctly requested.

Comment: CBC is **not** AEAD (although CBC+SHA2 does require TLS1.2).