# GCM cipher suites are enabled but not discovered by SSL Labs test

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have the following cipher suites enabled on Windows Server 2012 R2 server.

[image: Enabled cipher suites]

However, when I run SSL Labs test, the test discovers only the following cipher suites and the test reports `This server does not support Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites. Grade will be capped to B from March 2018.`.

[image: Discovered cipher suites]

Why are the `_GCM_` cipher suites missing in the test report? How to fix that?

Note: The web is delivered via IIS. Yeah, I have restarted the server. The `GCM` cipher suites should be the one that the `AEAD` message is talking about as of [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136180/tls-1-2-and-enable-only-aead-ciphers-suite-list).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You show various *ECDSA*GCM* ciphers as enabled. But these are all cipher suites which require an ECDSA certificate, i.e. with an ECC public key. My guess is that you instead use the more common RSA certificate which means that no ECDSA ciphers can be used. Instead you would need to enable *RSA*GCM* ciphers, for example `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`

Comment: It seems you are right, the certificate states "SHA-256 with RSA Encryption". However, I do not see any `*_ECDHE_RSA_*_GCM_*` certificates listed on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt767781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx so I guess they are not supported on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: @alik: Yes, this seem to be the case. There are TLS_DHE_RSA_\*_GCM_\* ciphers but I don't recommend these since DHE key exchange is way slower than ECDHE and thus hurts the performance. There are also TLS_RSA_\*_GCM_\* ciphers but I don't recommend these either since these use RSA key exchange and don't provide forward secrecy.

Comment: Ok, so I just should wait till we upgrade the server OS.

Comment: You can do that, or request a new certificate with the ECDSA and RSA ciphers in it so both can be active. While it's not ideal that MS doesn't have the ECDHE_RSA*GCM suites on 2012R2 and lower, you can workaround it with the new certificate.

Comment: @Lutzer: A certificate has no ciphers in it but keys. And it can only contain a single public key, i.e. either RSA or ECC (i.e. for ECDSA) but not both. The workaround you propose is impossible.